# Is it (easily) possible to deactivate a TPM in order to update the BIOS?

Tags: tpm, bios

My assumption is that a BIOS update, while having a TPM activated, would render the computer unusable so that I could trash it unless I can revert the changes to the BIOS.

1) Is it possible to deactivate the TPM, for example in order to install a Bios update, and then activate it again?

2) If it is possible to deactivate a TPM (only from within a running OS I assume), then is the following conclusion true? The TPM only protects against attackers who do not have access to the running operating system (= operating system after it has booted).

Comment: If a TPM would render a computer unusable after a BIOS update, don't you think there'd be instructions with each BIOS update on how to perform it?

Comment: I guess that having an activated TPM and updating the BIOS works somehow. But how? Do you diactivate the TPM in order to update the Bios?